# How to add icon to the items in the overflow menu in the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Part of the code in my `menu.xml` is:

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/action_settings"
  android:orderInCategory="100"
  android:title="@string/action_settings"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  app:showAsAction="never"/>`
```

However, the icons don't show in the app. What is my mistake?

Comment: overflow is not suppose to show icon, it is text only.

Comment: I have seen apps where there are icons why?

Comment: you mean, you want to have a Icon in menu item? or you want to change overflow icon itself?

Comment: I want to have a icon in menu item

Comment: It is not normal to have icons on overflow and goes against Android guidelines.

Comment: I want a menu like this   --->   http://blogs.embarcadero.com/files/2013/10/overflow2_9814.PNG

Comment: posted an answer try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want icon you need to change the value of ShowAsAction="never" to ShowAsAction="always"

Try the next code.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_options"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_config"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_config"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_close"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_close"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: so, however, the items are no longer present in the overflow menu

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might solve you problem, try it out..

In onPrepare callback of menu after menu creation, you just do this for all the menu items, before returning it back again

```
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.'your_menu_resource', menu);
    int length = menu.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++){
        MenuItem item  = menu.getItem(i);
        item.setIcon('your_resource_identifier')
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: hey you didnt write that excatly right, what i meant is that you need to retrive/loop all the menu items and perform that action. incase you get confused, i have edited my code itself,

Answer (score 0):

In your menu xml, use the following syntax to nest menu, you will start getting the menu with icons

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_show_ir_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_friendslist"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="List"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```